# How to print html page content to printer

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using `vue-html-to-paper` plugin to print some content but every time on click I am getting error as `[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: m is null"` I am using vue.js frame work

**What I have done**

**main.js**

```
import print from 'vue-html-to-paper'
Vue.use(print)
```

**in my test.vue**

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <!-- SOURCE -->
    <div id="printMe">
      <h1>Print me!</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- OUTPUT -->
    <button @click="print"></button>
  </div>
</template>
  <script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      output: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    print() {

      this.$htmlToPaper('printMe');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I have gone through the docs, I am doing exact the same but getting same error.

[Git Link](https://github.com/mycurelabs/vue-html-to-paper#readme)

Comment: Are you sure that error comes from the vue-html-to-paper sample? Also, try to avoid naming component same as the method for the other component, use the name from the sample they gave.

Comment: @niklaz is there any other plugin to do the same, I have tried `print-nb` but is not very vast range.